# does tf.function create graph for other functions that it called as well?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I dont know how exactly the `tf.function` traces the function that is calling other decorated functions. What is the difference between calling, from within a decorated function, the functions that are decorated vs the functions that are not decorated

```
@tf.function
def x1(a,b):
  return a+b
```

```
def x2(a,b):
  return a+b
```

```
@tf function
def y(a,b):
  return a+b+x1(a,b)+x2(a,b)
```

What happens when the function y is traced by tf.function? If this is the only use `x1` and `x2` are ever going to serve then does it make sense to decorate `x1` with @tf.function?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot find a source for this right now, but generally *everything* in the scope of a decorated function will be traced/turned into a graph. That is, in your specific case, there is no need to decorate `x1` or `x2` if they are only called from inside `y`. As such, it is usually sufficient to decorate only the top-most function one wants to be traced (e.g. the function calling the model, or running a single training step, or...)

Comment: Thank you for your help kind friend. If you could provide a source and/or an example demonstrating the validity of answer i would be glad to accept and upvote